# How do I have dark elixir with no storage

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have dark elixir that I use with my dark barracks but I have no storage for it. How do I posses it and use it without storage?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, can you click the check mark on it? Otherwise, what can I do to make it better?

Answer (score 8):

If you townhall is level 7 or higher, it can hold dark elixir in it. It can hold 2,500 at th7, 5,000 at th8, 10,000 at th9, and 20,000 at th10+. Therefore you can hold dark elixir even without a dark elixir storage if you have a high enough townhall, but only in a smaller quantity.

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall)